# How do I take user input and put on path?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm very new to python. I want to capture user images by taking user input first and creating a folder in the train and test directory using the given input. For example if user inputs "Bill" as his name, the train and test directory will create a folder named Bill and store images in the particular train folder from webcam. What I got so far is:

```
originaldir='C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Deep-Learning-Face-Recognition-master'
trainingdir='C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Deep-Learning-Face-Recognition master\\Datasets\\Train'
testingdir='C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Deep-Learning-Face-Recognition-master\\Datasets\\Test'
username = input("Enter username:")
print("Username is: " + username)
os.chdir(trainingdir)
os.mkdir(username)
os.chdir(testingdir)
os.mkdir(username)
```

I am able to create folders of the user's given name but I am not able to store photos captured from webcam in the specific training folder. It throws a syntax error.

```
file_name_path = trainingdir '/'  username  '/' + '.jpg'
cv2.imwrite(file_name_path, face)
```

I'm getting the syntax error below:

```py
file_name_path = trainingdir '/' username '/' + '.jpg'  SyntaxError: invalid syntax –
```

Comment: Could you give us the details of the syntax error you are facing? It will help us identify the problem.

Comment: Everyone who is very new to python jumps straight to Machine Learning and AI..Always found that to be strange. :)

Comment: To assemble string variables together you need to use the operator `+` as in `trainingdir + '/' + username` but since you are working with Windows paths it would be better to use the Windows path separator \. If you want your code to be platform independent then don't use a literal `'\\'` but instead use `os.path.sep` which has the separator appropriate to the platform. Or avoid this problem altogether by using `pathlib.Path` instances instead of strings. `trainingdir=pathlib.Path('C:\\Users\\...etc...\\Train')` then `file_name_path=trainingdir / username`.

Comment: @AbishekRai Not strange if your primary interest is ML and learning Python is just a means to that end. Python's success is because it is well suited to people who are primarily sociologists or linguists or numerical mathematicians or musicologists, not computer scientists or professional programmers.

Comment: @BoarGules Probably. I guess it needs a very narrow understanding of python itself. That explains it.

Comment: I'm not *quite* new to reading. I spot a blank in `trainingdir` where the others have a dash. Recommend `trainingdir = originaldir + '\\Datasets\\Train'` and **against** `os.chdir()`.

Answer (score 1):

A way with string format:

```py
file_name_path = "%s/%s/%s.jpg" % (trainingdir, username, filename)
```

Answer (score -3):

if you are creating the path by adding strings you need to use '+' operator for each string.

like:

```
file_name_path = trainingdir + '/' + username + '/' + str(count) + '.jpg'
```

Comment: **do not** use double forward slashes. that's invalid. single forward slash is correct.

Comment: use os.path.join and os.path.expanduser
slashes are different in windows and unix